# hornetQ causes OutOfMemoryError during war deployment

Tags: java, spring, jboss, openshift

I have developed a java app, which uses mysql and is based on springframework v3.1.1 (I also tested with v4.1.7, but the same problem exists). When I deployed the app (ROOT.war) to a small gear for jboss EA6, the app was deployed successfully, but a series of OutOfMemoryErrors followed:

```
2015/07/19 22:36:14,483 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.4.1.GA (AS 7.5.1.Final-redhat-3) 
    started in 39584ms - Started 573 of 690 services (145 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2015/07/19 22:36:15,671 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.server] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) HQ222082: error on connection failure check: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:949) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1360) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] 
    ....
```

Since my application has nothing to do with hornetQ, I am puzzled why it caused errors.

I like to point out that these errors only appear with small gear (512M memory). Medium and higher gears are OK.

Comment: Either you have some associations which are EAGER fetching causing out of memory error or your project is too big for 512MB, or you have memory leaks.. These are the ones I can think out of hat, but without seeing the project architecture and understanding how it works, it's difficult to isolate...you should turn on debug logging for spring, hibernate, java, and go through the log files before the error happens..That way you will be able to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll follow the suggestion.

Comment: My app is a small one (less than 1M of my own java code). It uses MYSQL and Spring (Restful ws on server side, TX management). Is this sufficient to conclude that my app is NOT too big for 512M memory?

Comment: Well, less then 1mb of Java code is still a lot. Our project for example has only 250kb of java code but has more then 12 model classes. And yes, it requires a lot of ram. Like I said, you also have to check for memory leakage and post the debug msgs for hibernate, spring before error happens...Even a simple thread in a loop can cause out of memory errors...So code size is irrelevant... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `OutOfMemoryError` is a bit confusing, It mean that the JVM is out of system resource (memory, threads, etc), in your case could not start a new thread.

On the other hand  in Openshift the small gears have a thread limit of 250 threads.

See the following discussion: https://forums.openshift.com/javalangoutofmemory-on-simple-app